custom module function call referenced ones , but it gets called multiple times
I have a streamlit based question/answering project, which has following structure.
files/loader.py
files/pdf.py
files/database.py
files/query.py
app.py

Modules called by in order such as:
app.py(streamlit chatbot functionality built inside of this file)>>>pdf.py(one upload file streamlit functions to upload pdf and mp3 files and extend them inside of list)>>> loader.py(has code of to process every file kind and return data to pdf.py module)
pdf.py>> database.py(to save procecesed data in a chromadb)
app.py>> query.py(Retrieve data from chromadb and has function to answer queries and return answer by app.py)

app.py sample is:
    import different python modules
    from files import pdf
    other funcitions to process queries:
    class single_ques:
     def __init__(self):
     #some code
    class multiple_ques:
       def __init--(self):
     #some code
    
     
    def main():
      pdf.main()   # Here i called pdf module main function, which i want to be called only once
      if button==single_ques:
         single_ques()
      if button==multiple_ques:
         multiple_ques()

if __name__=='__main__;
main()

pdf.py sample is:
class doc:
      def __init__(self,path)
        self.document = self.load()
            if self.path.endswith(('.txt','.docx','.pdf')):
                self.chunks = self.chunking()
      def load(self):
        if self.path.endswith(.txt):
                #some code to process it from module in loder.py
           # same way for other file types
        def chunk:
           #chunking function
    
    def main:
      names=[]
            uploaded_files=st.file_uploader("Choose data files", accept_multiple_files=True)
            
            if uploaded_files:
                for up in uploaded_files:
                     names.append(up.name)
                    # with open(up.name,mode='wb') as w:
                    #     w.write(up.getvalue())
                if  names:
                    d={}
                    
            
                    for up in  names:
                        if up not in d:
                            RAG = doc(up)
                            documents = doc.load()
                            d[up]=True
                            uploaded_files=None
if __name__=='__main__';
main()

So when instead of uploading files , i provide hardcoded files addresses and run pdf.py files separately,means i dont call pdf.py module in app.py, ebverything work as expacted.
But i want to upload different files every time , if i run app.py, so it should create new database.
Problem is whenever i click some button or enter queries on alreday running chat bot, files processing repeated, and database got replaced. it keeps on process already uploaded files on each operation, unnecessary. i want pdf.py modules should be called only once, not for every queries file processing function be called.
Please help

Check the typo at the end of if __name__=='__main__;

that is typo  here only, its correct in original code

Please correct it (and any other typos) here. Otherwise people will be attempting to solve the wrong problem for you.
